# Angular 4/5: avoiding double subscribe

Tags: angular, rxjs

I need to capture a query parameter and then subscribe to an API to return results. I have done this using combineLatest but it seems overkill. Is there a way to simplify this please as I'm not needing to combine more than queryParamMap?

```
ngOnInit() {
  Observable.combineLatest([
    this.route.queryParamMap
  ])
  .switchMap(combined => {
    let page = combined[0].get('page');

    return this.service.getAll(); //{ page: page}
  })
  .subscribe(results => this.results = results.results);
}
```

Comment: `this.route.queryParamMap.switchMap(combined => ....).subscribe(...)`

Answer (score 1):

```
this.route.queryParamMap
  .switchMap(combined => {
  let page = +combined.get('page');
  return this.service.getAll()
})
.subscribe(
  results => this.results = results.results
);
```

Thanks for the replies.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, a simple

```
this.route.paramMap.switchMap((params: ParamMap) => {
  let page = +params.id.get('page');
  this.service.getAll().subscribe(x => { /* ... */);
});
```

Should do the trick !

Comment: Unfortunately I get this, but thanks for your help. type '(combined: ParamMap) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type '(value: ParamMap, index: number) => ObservableInput<{}>'.
  Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'ObservableInput<{}>'.

Comment: It was because I wasn't returning this.service.getAll() before subscribing to it.

All fixed. Many thanks.